# Why does ScrollBarVisibility.Auto hurt performance?

Tags: wpf, performance, richtextbox

An article about [Optimizing Performance in WPF Applications](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/VisualStudio/228_Optimizing_Performance_in_WPF_Applications.aspx) suggests:

> Whenever possible, avoid using the ScrollBarVisibility.Auto value for RichTextBox, ScrollViewer, and TextBox objects etc.

Why does `ScrollBarVisibility.Auto` supposedly hurt performance?

Comment: Same statement can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb613584%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Avoid_Using_ScrollBarVisibility), but reasons are not given either. I presume that the code for detecting whether to show ScrollBar or not is affecting performance somewhat.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it impacts performance *much*. Is this not just a case of Auto incurring a non-zero amount of processing overhead, versus providing a Visibility value requiring zero?